# Addressing first/last item in an ul, li

Tags: jquery

How do you check whether a DOM element being clicked is either the 'first' li element or the 'last' li element in an unordered list item??

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean last `li` in a `ul`?

Comment: Yes. I mean to say that. li in an ul.

Comment: I peeked at the code you had before you changed your question. Is the element being clicked an `img` in a `li`?

Comment: yes. It is an img. I was using like `$('.item img').click()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on your question as it appeared before your edit, as well as your comments, it seems you're responding to a `li img` being clicked, and trying to find out if that containing `li` is the first or last child.

Use [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is) together with [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) to check:

```
$('ul li img').click(function() {
    var $li = $(this).closest('li');

    if ($li.is(':first-child')) {
        // First
    } else if ($li.is(':last-child')) {
        // Last
    }
});
```

Comment: is the '$' in the '$li' necessary?

Comment: @ptamzz: No, it's just a personal convention for me to label jQuery variables using `$`. You can say something else like `var li = $(this).closest('li');
` and just use `li` in your `if` and `else if`.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
<ul class="myUnorderedList"><li>First</li><li>Last</li></ul>
```

js:

```
$('.myUnorderedList li').click(function(){

   if($(this).is(':first')) console.log('first li');
   if($(this).is(':last')) console.log('last li');

})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ***[first()](http://api.jquery.com/first/)*** and ***[last()](http://api.jquery.com/last/)***:

```
$('#ulid > li').first();
$('#ulid > li').last();
```

Comment: how does this help with a click fn?

Comment: Inside the click handler, you could simply check the object clicked against the first() or last() ...

Comment: You can't? That is interesting. I would think jQuery objects are singletons, meaning that it would only create a single wrapper object for a DOM element. But since jQuery objects are collections, then that doesn't really make sense.

Comment: I was able to do it, just need to use [0] after the objects.  Check out the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LcDun/).

Answer (score 0):

If this is your code:

```
<ul class="myUnorderedList"><li>First</li><li>Last</li></ul>
```

Then you can access it by the First selector (http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) or last selector ([enter link description here](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/)) as follows:

```
<script>$(".myUnorderedList>li:first").css("font-style", "italic");</script>

<script>$(".myUnorderedList>li:last").css("font-style", "italic");</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this could help

```
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

With this jquery code

```
$("li").click(function(){
   if ($("li:first").text() == $(this).text() ){
      alert("first");
   }
  if ($("li:last").text() == $(this).text() ){
     alert("last");
  }
});
```

See it on http://jsfiddle.net/GT7Mm/

Comment: let us say multiple items have the same text??